# Sharing a link from UWP App to Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-10, share, uwp

I am trying to share a link from my UWP App to any application using        `DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();`

I made these 2 functions:

```
 private void ShareButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTransferManager dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
            dataTransferManager.DataRequested += DataTransferManager_DataRequested;
            DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
        }

        private void DataTransferManager_DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            args.Request.Data.SetWebLink(new Uri("http://radio.com/"));
            args.Request.Data.Properties.Title = "Radio";
            args.Request.Data.Properties.Description = "I am listening to Radio.";
            args.Request.Data.SetText("I am listening to Radio.");
        }
```

When I click my Share Button then the Facebook App. Facebook opens and I get a different title, a different description and Text. And mostly I get an icon in the post. The icon is different from the ones I have in my app. The ones in my app have a blue background while the one in the Facebook post has a transparent background.

What I expect is that the data being shared comes from the link not from what I'm sending in the `args.Request.Data`. How to fix that?

Is setting `args.Request.Data.Properties.Square30x30Logo` will replace it? How to set this logo?

Answer (score 1):

This expected behavior is **not** yet supported on UWP. as it's on Android and iOS.

Instead you can use [Windows SDK for Facebook - feed dialog](http://microsoft.github.io/winsdkfb/#feed_dialog), and of course [Facebook native API](https://developers.facebook.com) is still a valid option.

[Samples for the Windows SDK for FB](http://microsoft.github.io/winsdkfb/sample/)